# How do I get two different random numbers in the same srand() seed? C++

Tags: c++, c++11, random, srand

I am trying to create a random password generator. When I call the function multiple times it returns the same character value. `QQpQ;7Q7pQ;p`

I have tried adding `srand(time(0));` or `srand((unsigned int) time(NULL));` in my main function.

Looking at other stack over flow posts I see that srand helps create different characters each time I run the program. However it still returns multiples of the same character.

**How can I change srand() seed during run time to get different random numbers?**

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

string randomGenerator(int numberOfCharacters);
char randomCapitalCharacter();
char randomLowerCharacter();
char randomSpecialCharacter();
char randomInt();

int main(){
    srand((unsigned int) time(NULL));
    int passwordLength = 12;
    string password = randomGenerator(passwordLength);
    cout << password << endl;
    return 0;
}

string randomGenerator(int numberOfCharacters){
    char randomCharacterTypes[4] = {randomLowerCharacter(),randomInt(), randomCapitalCharacter(), randomSpecialCharacter()};
    std::string password;

    while (numberOfCharacters > 0){
        int random = rand()%4;
        password += randomCharacterTypes[random];
        numberOfCharacters--;
    }
    return password;
}
char randomInt(){
    std::string numberAsString = to_string(std::rand()% 10);
    char randomNumberChar = numberAsString.at(0);
    return randomNumberChar;
}
char randomLowerCharacter(){
    return 97 + rand()%26; //97 = a
}
char randomCapitalCharacter(){
    return 65 + rand()%26; //65 = A
}
char randomSpecialCharacter(){
    /** Special characters are split by numbers so we pick a random from one of the 2 groups.*/
    return (rand()%2) ? char(33 + rand()%14) : char(58 + rand()%8); 
}
```

- [srand() — why call it only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-it-only-once)
- [Why does rand() yield the same sequence of numbers on every run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459035/why-does-rand-yield-the-same-sequence-of-numbers-on-every-run)

Comment: `randomCharacterTypes[4]` only contains 4 different characters, did you mean to create an array of function pointers?

Comment: When I run your code, the first time it prints `RReR>>eReR6e` and the second time it prints `g>g>7gTgg>>T`  Is it because you are running it more than once in the same second?  That would give the same values because time(NULL) returns an integer number seconds - so if you run it more than once in the same second time(NULL) would return the same value.

Comment: Since you are using c++11, you should stop using srand in favour of the new random number generators: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66850447/1294207

Comment: @AlanBirtles Oh I see yes I am trying to use function pointers. I see that if I just call the randomLowerCharacter(); that it does return a random character value. I will look up how to implement function pointers. Thank you!!!

Comment: You'd probably be better off using a switch statement after `int random = rand()%4;` to call the right function and get a character. Right now you're only calling each function once and storing the result in `randomCharacterTypes`. It looks like maybe you're hoping that you're calling the function each time but you're not and a switch may make more sense than trying to explain how function pointers work.

Comment: You can avoid the need for comments like `//97 = a` if you write `'a'` instead of `97` in the code (and similar for other characters)..

Comment: @RetiredNinja Perfect thank you that works beautifully. I'll still look into function pointers as I think it would look cleaner. But for now the switch statement has my program working as intended. Thank you!!

Comment: Don't put answers in your question. Write a proper answer instead. I rolled back to your original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`randomCharacterTypes` is an array of 4 characters, for each character class you'll always get the same character. If you want to generate a new character each time you could use function pointers instead:

```
string randomGenerator(int numberOfCharacters){
    char (*randomCharacterTypes[])() = {randomLowerCharacter,randomInt, randomCapitalCharacter, randomSpecialCharacter};
    std::string password;

    while (numberOfCharacters > 0){
        int random = rand()%4;
        password += randomCharacterTypes[random]();
        numberOfCharacters--;
    }
    return password;
}
```

`randomInt` can be simplified to return a character between `'0'` and `'9'` the same as your other functions:

```
char randomInt(){
    return '0' + rand() % 10;
}
```

Your other functions are more readable if you use character rather than numbers which you then have to add a comment to remind you which character they represent:

```
char randomLowerCharacter(){
    return 'a' + rand()%26;
}
char randomCapitalCharacter(){
    return 'A' + rand()%26;
}
char randomSpecialCharacter(){
    /** Special characters are split by numbers so we pick a random from one of the 2 groups.*/
    return (rand()%2) ? char('!' + rand()%14) : char(':' + rand()%8); 
}
```

note that [`rand() % x`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53040940/why-is-the-new-random-library-better-than-stdrand) is not a good random number generator and you should use the standard library random functions instead (especially if you are using these passwords for anything important).

Your code could possibly be further simplified using `string`s to contain your character classes:

```
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <array>

class PasswordGenerator
{
public:
    PasswordGenerator()
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < characterTypes.size(); i++)
        {
            characterTypeDistributions[i] = std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(0, characterTypes[i].size() - 1);
        }
    }

    static constexpr std::array<std::string_view, 4> characterTypes = {
            "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
            "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
            "0123456789",
            "!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@"
        };
    std::array<std::uniform_int_distribution<int>, characterTypes.size()> characterTypeDistributions;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> typeDistribution{0, characterTypes.size() - 1};
    std::mt19937 eng{std::random_device{}()};

    std::string generate(int numberOfCharacters){
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist{0, 5};
        std::string password;
        password.reserve(numberOfCharacters);
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCharacters; i++)
        {
            auto type = typeDistribution(eng);
            password += characterTypes[type][characterTypeDistributions[type](eng)];
        }
        return password;
    }
};

int main(){
    int passwordLength = 12;
    PasswordGenerator gen;
    std::string password = gen.generate(passwordLength);
    std::cout << password << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Note that this code may still not meet high security standards for generating passwords.

Comment: at least 600 MT19937 outputs are needed before having much of a chance of recovering its state, which you're well below here.  that said, it's probably better to just exclusively use `random_device` for the engine instead of using `mt19937` at all

Comment: @SamMason depends on the quality of `random_device`...

Comment: this is indeed permitted by the standard, but I'd be intrigued to know on what real implementations this would actually result in a less predictable password.  e.g. under linux, osx and windows with any mainstream compiler I'd certainly prefer not to involve `mt19937`

Answer (score 2):

Thank you to @RetiredNinja for pointing out that the problem wasn't with srand() but rather with the improper calling of functions in my array. Using a switch statement to call the functions properly fixed the issue.

```
//improper calling of functions in an array. Resolved with switch statement below
//char randomCharacterTypes[4] = {randomLowerCharacter(),randomInt(), randomCapitalCharacter(), randomSpecialCharacter()};

while (numberOfCharacters > 0){
    int random = rand()%4;
    switch(random){
    case 0:
        password += randomLowerCharacter();
        break;
    case 1:
        password += randomInt();
        break;
    case 2:
        password += randomCapitalCharacter();
        break;
    case 3:
        password += randomSpecialCharacter();
        break;
    }
    numberOfCharacters--;
}
```

Comment: You may simplify the loop a bit by dropping the decrementation at the end of the loop body and incorporating it in the conditition instead: `while(--numberOfCharacters >= 0) {...}`